# Time complexity of algorithms using two pointers.Is it 0(n) or 0(n^2)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

So this is the problem given.

Given an array of integers, return a new array where each element in the new array is the number of smaller elements to the right of that element in the original input array.

For example, given the array [3, 4, 9, 6, 1], return [1, 1, 2, 1, 0], since:

```
There is 1 smaller element to the right of 3
There is 1 smaller element to the right of 4
There are 2 smaller elements to the right of 9
There is 1 smaller element to the right of 6
There are no smaller elements to the right of 1
```

I came up with this two pointer algorithm.

```
 function lessThan(arr) {
  let results = [];
  let i = 0;
  let j = arr.length - 1;
  let count = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
      count++;
    }
    j--;
    if (j === 1) {
      results.push(count);
      count = 0;
      i++;
      j = arr.length - 1;
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

the pointer 'i' will start at the begining and 'j' will start at the end.
if 'j' is equal to 1.'i' gets incremented and 'j' reset to the end.
This goes on untill 'i' reaches the end of the array.(when 'i' is equal or greater than arr.length the while loop breaks).
According to what I know about time complexity.I guess as we go through the array only once it is O(n).
But shouldnt we be considering the fact that there are 'n' comparisions made with respect to 'j' as we go through?
I am new to competitive programming and Big O notation.Please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how you can do that in a way that's not ultimately O(n^2)

Comment: @Pointy I'm pretty certain you can do in `O(n log n)` if you keep a sorted array and traverse the input from right to left.

Comment: No you cannot @Bergi.If you sort it .For 9 there will be 4 elements lesser than it.But if you read the problem description.That would result it in a wrong answer

Comment: If you think about a very large array with a very wide range of values, it seems like a bunch of iteration is inevitable.

Comment: There might be a "dynamic programming" approach (if that term is still in use 40 years after I learned it) that would work, but I can never figure those out.

Comment: @Pointy This isn't really a dynamic programming problem. It's very similar to the problem of counting inversions, and can be done in `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **O(n²)**, you increment `i` every `len(arr)` iterations, and so until `i` reach `len(arr)`.

That give a complexity in `len(arr) * len(arr)` *i.e.* O(n²).

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange your code to

```
 function lessThan(arr) {
  let results = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    let j = arr.length - 1;
    let count = 0;
    while (j !== 1) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
        count++;
      }
      j--;
    }
    results.push(count);
    i++;
  }
  return results;
}
```

Yes, you've cleverly merged the nested loops into a single one, but that doesn't change its complexity. Notice that in your version, the `while` loop runs `arr.length ²` times, as `i` is not incremented on every iteration but only when `j == 1`.

From my updated version it's not only clearly visible that the code is `O(n²)`, but also that it's wrong: `j !== 1` (or `j > 1`) should compare to `i` instead of `1` - you only want to count the elements on the right.